# Windows media player gives error "Server execution failed" after trying to play file

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, freeze

Every once in a while when I try to play a file in WMP it'll hang for about 10 seconds, pop up an error saying "server execution failed." If try again it usually works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Try going into services, scroll down to Windows Media Player Network Sharing, click 'restart'.
Then restart your Computer. Worked for me so far.

edit:
I just found another solution that I did not yet try. But if the problem returns, I´m going to try it.

> Go to Control Panel\Programs and Features\Turn Windows features on or off\Uncheck all Media Features\Reboot\recheck WMP only.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before and I discovered that it was because Windows Media Player was timing out trying to read the hard drive. I finally switched hard drives and now I haven't had this problem again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click Start Button, type "cmd" in the search bar. The CMD icon will appear in the Start Menu.
2. Right click the CMD icon and click "Run as administrator".
3. In the popup window, type the following command line and press Enter.
   NET LOCALGROUP administrators "NT Authority\Local Service" /ADD
   You should receive a message “The command completed successfully”.

Answer (score -1):

1. Delete Window Media Player Folder in **C:\Program Files (x86)** (before you delete it you can copy it elsewhere to back it up if you are not sure).  If you can't delete it then use ioBit Unlocker to unlock and delete it.
2. Copy Window Media Player Folder from **C:\Program Files** to **C:\Program Files (x86)**

This worked for me.

Comment: This might work. I haven't tested it myself so I don't know. But I am pretty sure there are safer methods that can resolve this problem. I am mentioning this as this might break something in a worst case scenario.