# Server execution failed error in windows 7 windows media player

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows media player gives error “Server execution failed” after trying to play file](https://superuser.com/questions/160032/windows-media-player-gives-error-server-execution-failed-after-trying-to-play-f)

Hi,
I am getting above error whenever I try to start WMP. I have windows 7 home edition OS. I tried to reinstall WMP from control panel but even after reinstallation I am getting same error. 
Does anyone knows how to solve this problem? Why do WMP is giving such error? Why do it needs server?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/160032/windows-media-player-gives-error-server-execution-failed-after-trying-to-play-f/181290#181290

Comment: @Diskilla,
I have seen that question but no one has answered that question so I thought new question might attract attention. I have tried solution given in that question but it doesnt work.